# Creating custom view and findViewById returns null

Tags: android, adapter

First off, I apologize because I know variations of this question have been asked several times but I cannot seem to find anything that matches mine.

Within my code, for some reason, the call

TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.top_text);

returns null. I know the R.id.top_text returns a proper value looking at the debugger. As well, v is a view created from the inflater. I would think that if the xml file for the individual row is defined and the specific item within it is returning a reasonable value, the findView call shouldn't return null.

Below is the full code for the Custom adapter and the two xml files.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks

```
    public class ContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ResultSet>{

        Context _context;
        int _layoutResourceId;
        ArrayList<ResultSet> _results;

        public ContactAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId,ArrayList<ResultSet> results) {
            super(context, layoutResourceId,results);
            _context = context;
            _layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
            _results = results;
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
            }
            ResultSet row = _results.get(position);
            if (row != null) {
                    TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.top_text);
                    if (tt != null) {
                          tt.setText("Name: "+row.getName());                            }

            }
           return v;
        }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="VOKAL CONTACTS"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="385dp" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp">

     <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/img_icon"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:gravity="center_vertical" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/top_text"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
         android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
         android:gravity="center_vertical"
         android:textColor="#000000"
         android:textSize="22dp"
         android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: why do you keep an arraylist in an array adapter ? why not use getItem rather than the reference to your arraylist ?

Comment: Try to clean the project and then run it again.

Comment: I have tried cleaning it a few times with no success. As for the arraylist rational, that should affect this. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Can you add the full stacktrace with the exception from the logcat?

Comment: I don't get an exception. Since (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.top_text); returns null, then the code skips the part where it does anything to tt. So basically I just end up with an empty list

Comment: Check what `convertView` is. It's probably a different kind of view being returned, which doesn't have access to `R.id.top_text`.

Comment: Piro, convertView comes into the method as null. Since the method is automatically called within ArrayAdapter there is no way to pass it anything besides that. The layout inflator should give it a view that does have access to top_text because it contains that resource. At least that's what I think is going on. I'm really willing to entertain anything as I've been working on this for awhile now.

Comment: @BrettRansby convertView isn't always null if the ArrayAdapter decides to re-use a view (e.g. this should happen when you're scrolling the list). You can check this quickly in the debugger by setting a breakpoint, or even by removing the `if (v == null)` check, so that you always inflate a new view and see if this problem persists. This is of course in the end not the way to go but maybe it helps you to track down your problem.